# How to display attributes and skip when necessary in C#

Tags: c#, xml

```
string str = "<samples><sample>cancel</sample><sample intentref='BUSINESS_PAY'>make payment</sample></samples>";
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(str);  

XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/samples/sample");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
    
    string intent = xn.Attributes["intentref"].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(intent);
}
```

If you look at the (str) variable, you can see the XML tags. As you can see, some of the elements don't have 'intentref' attribute and some do. What I'm trying to do is print it like this:

| Intent | Sample |
| --- | --- |
| Unassigned | cancel |
| BUSINESS_PAY | make payment |

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string intent = xn.Attributes["intentref"]?.Value ?? "Unassigned";
```

See it work here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/ELgyJ6